# How do I perform daily, monthly SQL Server 2005 maintenance?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Team,

I have SQL Server 2005 and I am new to DBA role and wondering if there is any T-SQL Script/Stored Procedure out there that they will help me accomplish the following on regular basis - Daily, Weekly, Monthly Yearly.

1. Hardware Utilization and Performance
   (Memory, Available Disk Storage, and then CPU Utilization)
2. Database and Server Configuration
   (Database Settings, Database Status, Database Back Up Status - Completion, Max 
   Server Memory Settings)
3. Database Maintenance
   (SQL Server Logs, File Growth, Mirroring Monitor , Back up completion, Index
   Fragmentation)

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

> Hardware Utilization and Performance (Memory, Available Disk Storage, and then CPU Utilization)

If your site already has [SCOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Center_Operations_Manager) deployed, use SCOM, as is capable of monitoring SQL Server. Otherwise, pick something off the shelve, eg. [Bosun](http://blog.serverfault.com/category/monitoring-and-graphing/)

> Database Maintenance (SQL Server Logs, File Growth, Mirroring Monitor , Back up completion, Index Fragmentation)

Use Ola's [Index Maintenance](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) and [Backup](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) scripts.

Comment: I will look into your suggestion and let you know accordingly.

Further, I am a new accidental DBA and eventually my role is going to be a regular DBA. I am wondering whether you have a list of tasks that I should follow on Weekly, Monthly, Quarterly and Yearly basis. It will be much appreciated.

Thanks.